How Can i add External storage permission in react-native for andriod and ios both . I tried i show you details below
I'm facing an issue with requesting MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission on Android 11 and above. Despite having the correct permissions set in the AndroidManifest.xml file and using PermissionsAndroid in my React Native code, the app still cannot access external storage.
enter image description here
Context:
I’m trying to request storage permissions on Android devices with version 11 (API level 30) and above. Below is my current implementation
1.AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="true"/>
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission-group.CAMERA"/> -->

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:supportsRtl="true">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>


My function:-
Permissions Request Function:
I'm using the PermissionsAndroid API in React Native to request permissions. Here's the code I have for requesting the permissions
const requestStoragePermission = async () => {
    try {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >= 30) {
            const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                {
                    title: 'Downloader App Storage Permission',
                    message:
                        'Downloader App needs access to your storage so you can download files.',
                    buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
                    buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                    buttonPositive: 'OK',
                },
            );
            if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                console.log('Storage permission granted');
                return true;
            } else {
                console.log('Storage permission denied');
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                {
                    title: 'Storage Permission Required',
                    message:
                        'This app needs access to your storage to download files.',
                    buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
                    buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                    buttonPositive: 'OK',
                },
            );
            if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                console.log('Storage permission granted');
                return true;
            } else {
                console.log('Storage permission denied');
                return false;
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.warn('Permission request failed: ', err);
        return false;
    }
};

package.json
The relevant dependencies in my project are as follows:
 "dependencies": {
    "react-native-permissions": "^5.2.1",
    "react-native": "0.75.4",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    // other dependencies...
}

